# facebook graph api user returns 0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to use Facebook integration with Graph API
I registered with FaceBook, got my `appID` and `Secret`, downloaded the `facebook-php-sdk-master` and used this code:

```
      require_once("facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php");
      $config = array();
      $config[‘appId’] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
      $config[‘secret’] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
      $config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional
      $facebook = new Facebook($config);
      $user = $facebook->getUser();
      echo "user = ".$user;
```

Now when I try to use this code it always prints `user = 0`.
Have i Missed anything ?
ps: I have authorized the app too.
PPS: Could this because I am trying to test my code from localhost and facebook needs a website name for this to run ?
Thanks

Comment: You need to login with facebook, which gives your app' permission to access user information, [the login documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you have authorized the application.  Just because you created the app does not mean the app knows who you are or can access your data.

Here is more info about logging in: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/login/

Answer (score 1):

You first need to login and authorize the app.